# IndexError: list index out of range. How to resolve this?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, typeerror

Hi i am trying to plot data through k means,and i want a single figure with the labels as well,However i am not able to plot the data, and i referred from this example "https://github.com/donglinchen/text_classification/blob/master/text_clustering_and_visualization.ipynb"

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, sharey=True)
fig.set_size_inches(20, 10)
colors = ['green','orange', 'blue', 'purple', 'red']
for e in set(model.labels_):
    mark = model.labels_ == e
    axes[0].scatter(feature_pca[:, 0][mark], feature_pca[:, 1][mark], color=colors[e], label=e, alpha=0.9)
axes[0].legend().
```

But i am getting the plotted data as:[image]

Comment: In the statement before that one, `mark` can never be true.  A set can never be equal to one of the items in the set.  Have you done enough debugging to know which thing is the problem?  Is `axes` empty?  Does `feature_pca` have two columns?

Comment: I just ran the 'ext_clustering_and_visualization.ipynb' and it worked fine.

Comment: first you can use `print()` to see what you have in variables - it helps to see where can be the problem.